# Error: Cannot find module 'connect/middleware/session/memory'

Tags: socket.io

I have done `npm install connect` but `Error: Cannot find module 'connect/middleware/session/memory'` did not disappear in output. Which package  didn't I install?

`windows 7`

`C:\Users\guo\Desktop\js8_chat\chat>node -v
v0.10.26`

`C:\Users\guo\Desktop\js8_chat\chat>npm -v
1.4.3`

`express@3.5.1`

`var express = require('express'),
    sio = require('socket.io'),
    fs=require('fs'),
    path = require('path')
    url = require('url'),
    parseCookie = require('connect').utils.parseCookie,
    MemoryStore = require('connect/middleware/session/memory');`

error:

`module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'connect/middleware/session/memory'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\guo\Desktop\js8_chat\chat\chat.js:11:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)`

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "remains?"  Remains where?

Comment: I thought it could be solved by `install connect`. But i am wrong. `remain` means the error is still there. I think maybe I did not use it correctly.

Comment: The error is where?   What are you trying to run?  What OS?

Comment: Thanks. I have added more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to create a `MemoryStore` and `cookieParser` then you can create it like this:

```
var EXPRESS_SID_KEY = 'express.sid';
var COOKIE_SECRET = 'very secret string';
var cookieParser = express.cookieParser(COOKIE_SECRET);
var sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore();
app.configure(function () {
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.session({
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: { 
        httpOnly: true
    },
    key: EXPRESS_SID_KEY
    }));
});
```

And what you're trying to get above exists in express module and you have to look it as

```
var MemoryStore = require('express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session\memory')
```